# Why is $2\sqrt{x+1}-2\geq\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}$ for $x \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: inequality

I have found following formula stands:

$2\sqrt{x+1}-2\geq\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}$

($x \in \mathbb{N}$)

I have wondered why this is true. I have checked its rightness on the graph drawing tools, but I want to know the mathematical proof of this.

Although I can prove it for $x \in \mathbb{N}, x\geq2$, as following:

$2\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x}/2 \geq 2\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x}/2 = \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{x}\geq\frac{3}{2}\cdot \sqrt{2} \geq2$

and prove the rightness in case $x=1$ by direct calculation,

I want to know whether it is possible to prove this formula without dividing the case of $x=1$ and others.

Thank you.

Comment: Try using induction

Comment: Decide if you  are using $x$ or $t$. Then square both sides...

Comment: @LukeTux Thank you for your answer.
I have tried the induction proof by following way:
1. It is true for $x = 1$
2.Assuming it is true in $x$,
prove $2\sqrt{x+2} - 2 \geq \sqrt{t+1}/2$ as following direction:

$2\sqrt{x+2} - 2 -\sqrt{t+1}/2 \geq 2\sqrt{t+1} - 2 -\sqrt{t+1}/2$

And I am wondering how to do the left part of the proof

Comment: @YuvalPeres Thank you for your suggestion. and editting  I revised $t$ to $x$.

Comment: In the induction, try multiplying by $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: @LukeTux
Thank you for your advices. Based on your advice, I come up as following:

If it is true for x,
$2\sqrt{x+1} - 2 \geq \frac {\sqrt{x}}{2}$.
Then, multiplying by $\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x}}$, following is obtained:
$2\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}} - 2 \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x}} \geq \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{2}$.
As for the left side, 
$2\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}} - 2 \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x}} \leq 2\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{2}} - 2 $,
If I can show $\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x}} \leq \sqrt{x+2}$ is true, then this proof by induction is completed.
Could you please give me some hints to show this part? Thank you.

Comment: That last inequality is not true. We have to instead prove $\frac{2(x+1)-2\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x}} \leq 2\sqrt{x+2} - 2$. Since the difference is quite small, derivatives are useful

Comment: The last inequality is :
$2\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}} - 2 \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x}} \geq 2\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x}} -2$

(I wrote the formula mistakenly. It is not $2\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}} - 2 \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x}} \geq 2\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{2}} -2$)

$-2\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x}} = -2\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x}} = -2\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}} \leq -2$

Comment: In the above comment, I wrote mistakenly and the first two formula is not $\geq$, but should be $\leq$.
And as for $2\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}} \leq 2\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x}}$, thus, the following formula (also shown in above comments) is true:
$2\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}} -2\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x}} \leq 2\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x}} -2$

Comment: @LukeTux Also, there might be ways to prove deductive without using derivatives, it is really a strong way to use derivatives to prove it is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $y=\sqrt{x} \geq 1$ if $x\geq 1$. Then you have to prove $$4\sqrt{y^2+1}\geq 4+y$$ i.e. (you can square inequality since both sides are nonegative) $$16(y^2+1)\geq 16+8y+y^2$$ i.e.
$$y(15y-8)\geq 0$$ which is clearly true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is exactly very useful for to take the square of both sides to prove inquality.

Answer (score 2):

You can set $f(x)=2\sqrt{x+1}-2-\frac 12\sqrt{x}$

The derivative $f'(x)=\frac 1{\sqrt{x+1}}-\frac 1{4\sqrt{x}}$

It is zero when $(4\sqrt{x})^2=(\sqrt{x+1})^2\iff 16x=x+1\iff x=\frac 1{15}$

The derivative is $-$ then $+$ so $f$ is $\searrow$ then $\nearrow$ with a minimum in $\frac 1{15}$.

We could calculate $f(\frac 1{15})$ but since we are only interested in naturals let just calculate

$f(1)=2\sqrt{2}-2-\frac 12\sqrt{2}>0$ as you have noticed yourself.

And since it is increasing, it's true for all $x\ge 1$ not only integers.

---

For sake of completion, $f(\frac 1{15})=\frac 12\sqrt{15}-2<\frac 12\sqrt{16}-2=0$

So there exists a zero of $f$ in the interval $[\frac 1{15},1]$ in addition to $x=0$.

We can calculate it by squaring both sides:

$(2\sqrt{x+1})^2=(2+\frac 12\sqrt{x})^2\iff 4x+4=4+\frac 14x+2\sqrt{x}\iff\frac {15}4x=2\sqrt{x}\iff \\\sqrt{x}=\frac{8}{15}\text{ or }x=0$

So actually the inequality is true for all $x\ge \frac{64}{225}$

***Side note**: this direct calculation of the zero, shows there are only two zeroes, $x=0$ and $x=\frac{64}{225}$, so you can deduce directly (without derivative) that since $f(1)>0$ and $f$ is continuous then $f$ cannot change sign on $[1,+\infty)$*

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Using derivative is actually a good way to prove this. I didn't consider this way.

Comment: Thank you for your additional remarks and sharing aother solution.
 I have a question regarding it, is the fact "f cannot change sign on $[1, \infty)$" deduced from "the continuity of f" and the fact that there is no x where f(x) = 0 in $[1, \infty)$?

Comment: Yes it's because $f$ is continuous which is quite immediate, should have mentioned it.

Comment: +1 and I was about to answer this way but scroll down and saw your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}=\dfrac{a-b}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$ , we have
$$\begin{aligned}2\sqrt{x+1}-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}&=\frac12\left(4\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}\right)\\
&=\frac12\cdot\frac{16(x+1)-x}{4\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}\\
&=\frac{15x+16}{2(4\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x})}\\
&\geqslant\dfrac{15(x+1)}{10\sqrt{x+1}}\\
&=\dfrac32\sqrt{x+1}\\
&\geqslant\frac32\sqrt{2}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac92}>2 \end{aligned}$$
for $x\in\mathbb{N}$, so in fact the inequality is strict.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried rationalizing denominator, but I couldn't find any good ways to evaluate the result of the formula after it by myself.